# Is there a way in LaTeX to separate the endnote text from the place where it should be placed/invoked?

Tags: endnotes

I want to insert a few fairly large endnotes. The problem is that if I insert them with `\endnote{text text}` it makes it very difficult to follow the flow of the main text (as the endnote spans a few paragraphs).

Is there a package that would allow me to separate the place where the endnote is invoked from its contents? Something like say `\lendnote{Label1} to invoke and \begin{lendnote}\label{Label1}<<here goes the endnote body>>\end{lendnote}`

Answer (score 5):

Here's a simple way to do this. You store each big endnote in a separate file named `<label>.tex` where `<label>` is how you will refer to it in the command that will insert it and in any `\ref` in the text. Then you create a command (I've called it `\extendnote`) which takes the label as an argument and then simply uses `\input` for the endnote text.

You can keep all of the external endnotes in the source file by adding them at the beginning using the `{filecontents}` environment. Of course if that becomes unmanageable, you can put all the `{filecontents}` environments in a separate file (e.g. `bignotes.tex`) and then `\input` that into your main source file.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{filecontents}[noheader,overwrite]{big.tex}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}[noheader,overwrite]{large.tex}
\lipsum[3-4]
\end{filecontents}
\newcommand{\extendnote}[1]{\endnote{\input{#1}\label{#1}}}
\begin{document}
Here is some text.\endnote{This is a small endnote\label{small}} 
Here is some more text, with a big endnote.\extendnote{big} Here is some
more text.\endnote{A small endnote} and some more text.\extendnote{large}.
And here are some references to note \ref{large} and note \ref{small}.
\theendnotes
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can store the note text in a macro, defined sowhere earlier in the source code.

An example (partially borrowed from the Alan Munn's answer):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcommand\noteone{\lipsum[1-2]}
\newcommand\notetwo{\lipsum[3-4]}
\begin{document}
Here is some text.\endnote{This is a small endnote} Here is some more text,
with a big endnote.\endnote{\noteone} Here is some more text.\endnote{A small
endnote} and some more text.\endnote{\notetwo}
\theendnotes
\end{document}
```

Comment: Right. I put `\def` mechanically, it's shorter then `\newcommand`, so I rarely use the latter.

Comment: Yes, me too sometimes, but for the site we should try to model best practice. :) (We can delete these comments).